# Is it possible to zoom in a Shield UI Pie Chart?

Tags: shieldui

Why can’t I zoom in a Shield UI Pie Chart? Are there any settings to be enabled? I tried the

```
zoomMode: 'xy',
```

property, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t zoom in on a pie chart. Nor do I see any need to. The only case you might need to do that is if the size of the pie is misset and it is bigger than the chart’s plot. Even if there was some possibility it would be resizing, and not zooming, since all the data is visible constantly.